# Hyper-V create VM with existing .vhdx

Tags: uefi, hyper-v

I'm using Hyper-V Manager on Windows 10. I've created a virtual machine and a virtual hard drive, I've installed OS and other software on it.

Now I'm trying to use this hard drive for other virtual machines. I've copied it in another location and when creating new virtual machine I pointed this copy as an existing drive. When I started the new virtual machine I got a black screen with `PXE Network Boot using IPv4 (ESC to cancel) Performing DHCP Negotiation....`. After several minutes I got new black screen with saying `DHCP failed` and `no x64-based UEFI boot loader was found`.

What I'm missing?

I create second generation virtual machines and also I have disabled the secure boot option, if it matters... When creating I used the same settings, I've changed only the hostname for the new VM.

Answer (score 4):

To create a virtual machine off of an existing VHDX, do as follows:

1. Create the virtual machine, setting its name, location, RAM assignment, network switches as usual until you get to the "Create a hard drive" screen. Here, select "Attach a hard disk later"
   [image: Attach Later]
2. Next, open the VMs settings and head to iSCSI controller. Add a new Hard Disk here, and point to where your copy of the VHDX is stored
   [image: Pick your hard drive]
3. This is where I believe you are stuck. After adding the hard drive, your boot entries will still be set to NETWORK -> HDD. You need to reverse this. Head to Firmware, and select "Hard Drive". Then hit "Move Up" on the right hand side. Apply the changes, and hit OK.
   [image: Move Up]

Your VM should now boot into the OS on the drive

Comment: Thank you very much for you time, this is the nicest answer I've ever had. However, I have already tried this and it didn't work. I will post as a comment my solution :)

Comment: Please do, I would like to know what your solution was.

Comment: @barni - You should update your question to reflect that fact then

Answer (score 3):

The trouble in my case was that I'd installed on the .vhdx Ubuntu. It seems that this OS does not create automatically the .efi file if it does not exist (.efi is the file from which the VM boots). So, the solution is:

```
 1. add DVD drive to the VM
 2. specify the same image file from which is loaded the OS on the .vhdx
 3. boot in rescue mode
 4. after a few quick setups(language, time zone, etc.), you'are asked 
for device to use as root file system, then choose **/dev/sda2/** 
(I'm not sure why is that :( )
 5. click Yes to mount separate /boot/efi partition
 6. from the rescue operation menu, choose 
**Force GRUB installation to the EFI removable media path**
 7. confirm this choice 
 8. you are ready to reboot and disconnect the image file :)
```

main source of this solution: https://blog.jhnr.ch/2017/02/23/resolving-no-x64-based-uefi-boot-loader-was-found-when-starting-ubuntu-virtual-machine/

Comment: Thanks, works also on Debian 10.

Comment: Followed the same steps and can confirm it works with Devuan ascii 2.1 also.

Answer (score 3):

When UEFI boots it searches Boot variables stored in NVRAM (it is emulated in Hyper-V) and search for any boot variable. When you create new VM its NVRAM is empty and UEFI does not know what file on the disk can be used as bootloader. You must create boot entry (which is in Hyper-V visualised as File boot option) manually. Hyper-V has no way how to do it from the host but you can do it from the guest itself. You need only know where the bootloader is located. It is `something.efi` (usualy `bootx64.efi`) file located somewhere on the EFI System Partition (ESP) which is normal FAT32 partition and contains some files. In Linux this partition is mounted to /boot directory. You can look for it at original machine. For debian for example it is in `EFI/debian/shimx64.efi`, but you can just try find and try any efi file you find in /boot folder at your original computer with linux.

You need to create small bootable media with UEFI Shell (aka. EDK II) and creates boot entry manually using it. You can do it in the following way.

1) Download latest release of EDK II UEFI SHELL (at write time of this post it is  ShellBinPkg.zip) from [GitHub](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/releases)

2) Using disk manager create new small VHDX disk (capacity 100MB is sufficient).

[image: Create VHDX]
[image: Create VHDX]

3) Initialize that disk.

[image: Initialize disk]
[image: Initialize disk]

4) Create new FAT32 partition

[image: Create FAT32]
[image: Create FAT32]
[image: Create FAT32]
[image: Create FAT32]

5) In the newly create partition (in my case letter is E: as you can see at previous screenshot) create directory `EFI` and and `EFI\boot`.

6) From downloaded zip archive copy `UefiShell/X64/Shell.efi` file to `EFI\boot` folder and rename it to `bootx64.efi`

7) detach virtual disk.

[image: Detach VHDX from host computer]
[image: Detach VHDX from host computer]

8) add virtual disk to your VM.

[image: Attach VHDX to VM]
[image: Attach VHDX to VM]

9) Temporarily disable Secure Boot of your VM.

[image: Temporarily disable secure boot]

9) Go to the firmware tab and move edkii.vhdx as first boot option.

[image: Boot order settings]
[image: Boot order settings]

10) Start VM. You will see EDK II UEFI SHELL.

[image: EFI Shell]

11) Enter the following command containing path to bootloader.

```
bcfg boot add 0 fs0:\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi` NAME_OF_DISTRIBUTION
```

[image: EFI SHELL Add boot option command]

12) reboot using `reset` command. Now you will successfully boot and in Firmware settings in Hyper-V you will see required File boot option.

[image: File boot option]

13) detach disk with EFI shell and restore SecureBoot settings.

Comment: In case anyone is looking at this solution, the latest TianoCore EDK II release with ShellBinPkg.zip was 2019-05.

Comment: Thank you so much! This should have been the marked answer, and also the most upvoted answer of the year!

Comment: @kkm - Your [suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1140618) may be perfectly valid (and probably is)... however, it seems too extensive a change (and deviates too much from the original work). However, it seems a shame to lose your hard work, so (if I were you) I would (copy the suggestion and) post it as your own updated answer. Also, the list formatting should be fixed and the images correctly indented for each numbered list item. And add image hover tags.

Comment: This answer, while technically correct, is often not needed: Bootloaders/-managers following the conventions (located on the ESP at `efi/boot/bootx64.efi`) will just work. Microsoft could even have added further conventions of their own.

Comment: @daniel-b Yes it is. But this "easier" method requires copying/renaming bootloader before migration to different machine and this is different situation than was asked. This tutorial rather describes situation when you already migrated and you need to fix it. You of course can mount VHDX of new machine and rename bootloader localy, but this is similarly complicated to this tutorial since Windows do not allow assign letters and work with system paritions like ESP partitions easily.

Comment: I’m not referring to manual action or fixing it this way. I’m saying that many bootloaders follow this convention _already_ and will work out of the box. This is especially true for “cloud images” that are sometimes available.

Comment: @daniel-b For this cases the question and answer is irelevant because exactly as you said, when you use distribution or image which uses this fallback name, then there is no isseu and Hyper-V will boot properly. Question is about distributions who do not do this and require Boot#### option for booting.

Comment: @Greenonline, obviously I cannot plagiarize someone else's answer as mine. The edits are done with (a) to make wording precise and (b) improving grammar (although I'm also pretty sloppy with it). Even after my edit, the walkthrough semantics, screenshots, and most of text, even if copyedited, are 90% original. Use it or lose it, I see no other option here. I'm ok with either, although it will certainly discourage my further edits: My edit removing an _ad hominem_ at the questioner was accepted then reverted by the author of the answer, so the site is not correction-friendly, as I feel.

Comment: @DanielB, I would not even start searching for a solution if I did not have the problem. For some reason, Debian prefers registering a boot application that following the `EFI/BOOT/bootPPPP.efi` convention. Possibly this makes dual-boot with Windows easier. Another options is to register Debian loader in the MS' bootloader BCD, kinda chain-load, but it depends on the installation order. Maybe you'll find an explanation in Debian list archives, but the fact is it ended up this way. And I have no idea how to tell the shim to look in efi/debian, even if I renamed it into the conventional place.

Comment: @DanielB, oh, as as for cloud images, a vanilla Debian image at the Google cloud has a custom boot/bootx64.efi that modifies UEFI Boot#### variables and resets the machine on first boot.